# Wifi dongle for internet and Ethernet for SSH to Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, ethernet, wpa

I am not able to connect to wireless networks for internet using wifi dongle in my raspberry pi. I connect PI to Desktop using ethernet for SSH. I modified interfaces file and wpa-supplicant.conf file adding wireless networks as mentioned in online tutorials. But none helped so far.

I get error :

wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start raspberry pi

But I can still ssh to pi using ethernet.

Please help.

Comment: Could you post your wpa-supplicant.conf file (**WARNING** remove any sensitive information from it by replacing them with "********" for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest Raspbian (May 2015) `wpa_supplicant daemon` is not used. Most of the tutorials on the web DO NOT work with this release.

See current instructions at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md